# Curious minimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

Well, this problem may look easy, but I'm not able to get the equations to minimize.

We have a hole in the floor and need to make a lid for it so that:

i) It can never fall into the hole, that is, the lid cannot pass through the constructed hole, in no position. We understand that the cap is slightly larger than the hole
(with the same shape) and that at the bottom of the lid there is a small edge, very close to the edge of the lid, to fit the gap.

ii) We have some flat rectangular metal plates, a little less than 70 centimeters inwide by three meters long. These plates must be able to pass through the hole.

iii) They should use the least amount of material possible, to minimize costs, but respecting
the above requirements.

We are asked to get the exact area of the lid.

Any help to translate it to a math language and how to solve it, would be really nice.

Comment: How far have you got?

Comment: Would a hole 1 cm by 71 cm let the plates pass?  Are you allowed to orient the plates like this?

Comment: What is the connection between the plates and the lid ?

Comment: @rossMilikan yeah I think so, nothing tell us not to accept that.

Comment: @user619894  I reached the conclusion that the diagonal of the hole (which is the longest straight line of the hole) should be equal to the minimum side of the plates(0,70) I cant do more at the moment

Comment: @YvesDaoust It just help us to figure out the size of the hole, nothing more I think

Comment: Is this a mathematics site, or a translate-my-homework-to-mathematics site?

Comment: @ProfessorVector you are pretty wrong, not even close, not homework, just a riddle making a math student wonder how, have a rigorous evening!

Comment: A riddle site, then, that's so very much better, indeed.

Comment: Did you reproduce the exact question or rephrased it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I translated it, but I'm 99% sure we are not losing anything on translation, it looks pretty ambigous in spanish too

Answer (score 0):

Make the hole just large enough to pass the plate through, something like 1 cm by 70 cm.  The problem is that you can orient the lid with the 70 cm longways.  You need a thick part of the lid that is more than 1 cm.  It doesn't need to be much.  A 1.25 by 1.25 cm part on the end of the lid will be enough.  There is no absolute minimum for the lid, as it needs to be wider than 1 cm but can be any amount wider.

Comment: Mmm, yeah thats correct, it's pretty ambiguous, but it asks for an exact answer. I think there`s something tricky in the thick parts we need to put in the borders, related to this minimum length diference between the hole and the lid

Comment: How can you give an exact answer when the input data is approximate? You need exact dimensions of the plates and the minimum allowed lip on the lid

Comment: Yes, that's the problem